# Rest service with WCF and wsdl definition

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, wsdl

i read on the net that there is no wsdl definition for REST services and also that in WCF we can use `webHttpBinding` to create restful services. I downloaded SOA cleaner software to test my services and its screen confused me a littel. Plz have a look at following shot
[image]
Now look that `webHttpBinding` is selected which is supposed to be a REST service and this software is asking for wsdl definition of this service. However if i switch to second option which is Plain Http(s) /REST it only requires a url to communicate with that service. Does REST have a wsdl or doesn't webHttpBinding provide REST service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST Services can only be described by by WADL or WSDL 2.0 which is not supported by WCF. [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030749/wsdl-for-rest-wcf) my help you out.