# How to choose between JAX-RS and JAX-WS web services implementation?

Tags: java, jax-ws, jax-rs

In what contexts is it better to use one over the other and why?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST and SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap)

Answer (score 18):

JAX-WS is an API for SOAP-based WS, and using it for RESTful WebServices is not the best way to go about things.

So if you're looking to implement a RESTful WebService,  use JAX-RS .

Comment: it looks like JAX-RS 2 is contained in JAX-WS. see http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/index.html . what do I make of this?

Answer (score 5):

I feel like Web services are mostly tied for `UDDI` type applications. `REST` is just a plain evolution to make stateless `http` protocol to stateful thing by using `http` method communications for doing `CRUD` operations. Like mapping operations to methods `GET, PUT, POST` and `DELETE`.

Web Services are into coding for Airplane ticket reservation systems, Online banking, payment gateways, etc. Where there are a set of standard systems expose their API in some definitions. The `JAX-RS` is for providing some light weight layer for resources...

Comment: dont really understand your words "Normal people can not achieve such things using plain JAX-RS.."

Comment: I meant JAX-RS is not meant to solve what Web Services is used for in a full manner.

Comment: You should read this http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/

Answer (score 0):

Jax-WS supports both SOAP and ReST, however if you need the features of the WS* protocols, JAX-WS is the right API. Due to this JAX-WS is somewhat complex to use in comparison to ReST.