# What is the difference between JAX-RS and JAX-WS?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, jax-ws, jax-rs

After reading a few articles about JAX-RS and JAX-WS, I had a few questions that I want to confirm?

1. Can JAX-RS do Asynchronous Request like JAX-WS?
2. Can JAX-RS access a web service that is not running on the Java platform, and vice versa?
3. What does it mean by "REST is particularly useful for limited-profile devices, such as PDAs and mobile phones"?
4. What does it mean by "JAX-RS do not require XML messages or WSDL service–API definitions?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> Can JAX-RS do Asynchronous Request like JAX-WS?

1) I don't know if the JAX-RS API includes a specific mechanism for asynchronous requests, but this answer could still change based on the client implementation you use.

> Can JAX-RS access a web service that is not running on the Java platform, and vice versa?

2) I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be able to.

> What does it mean by "REST is particularly useful for limited-profile devices, such as PDAs and mobile phones"?

3) REST based architectures typically will use a lightweight data format, like JSON, to send data back and forth. This is in contrast to JAX-WS which uses XML. I don't see XML by itself so significantly heavier than JSON (which some people may argue), but with JAX-WS it's how much XML is used that ends up making REST with JSON the lighter option.

> What does it mean by "JAX-RS do not require XML messages or WSDL service–API definitions?

4) As stated in 3, REST architectures often use JSON to send and receive data. JAX-WS uses XML. It's not that JSON is so significantly smaller than XML by itself. It's mostly that JAX-WS specification includes lots overhead in how it communicates.

On the point about WSDL and API definitions, REST will more frequently use the URI structure and HTTP commands to define the API rather than message types, as is done in the JAX-WS. This means that you don't need to publish a WSDL document so that other users of your service can know how to talk to your service. With REST you will still need to provide some documentation to other users about how the REST service is organized and what data and HTTP commands need to be sent.

Answer (score 101):

Another important point

JAX-WS represents SOAP

JAX-RS represents REST

[How to choose between JAX-RS and JAX-WS web services implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108710/how-to-choose-between-jax-rs-and-jax-ws-web-services-implementation)

Comment: Actually,JAX-WS represents both RESTful and SOAP based web services. One way to think about it is that JAX-RS specializes in RESTful, while JAX-WS allows you more flexibility to choose between either, while at the same time being (in some cases) more complicated to configure.

Comment: Thank you for simple explanation.

Comment: "*JAX-WS represents both RESTful and SOAP based web services*" - this is not true, can you please put some reference to validate your claim, JAX-WS can transport SOAP over HTTP and also XML over HTTP, but this makes JAX-WS RESTful. Being RESTful is entirely different concept.

Answer (score 52):

[JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services) - is Java API for the XML-Based Web Services - a standard way to develop a Web- Services in [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) notation (Simple Object Access Protocol).

Calling of the Web Services is performed via remote procedure calls. For the exchange of information between the client and the Web Service is used SOAP protocol. Message exchange between the client and the server performed through [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)- based SOAP messages.

Clients of the JAX-WS Web- Service need a [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) file to generate executable code that the clients can use to call Web- Service.

[JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) - Java API for RESTful Web Services. RESTful Web Services are represented as resources and can be identified by Uniform Resource Identifiers ([URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier)). Remote procedure call in this case is represented a [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)- request and the necessary data is passed as parameters of the query. Web Services RESTful - more flexible, can use several different [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)- types. Typically used for XML data exchange or [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (JavaScript Object Notation) data exchange...

Comment: Short and crisp explanation!! Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

> Can JAX-RS do Asynchronous Request like JAX-WS?

Yes, it can surely do use @Async

> Can JAX-RS access a web service that is not running on the Java platform, and vice versa?

Yes, it can Do

> What does it mean by "REST is particularly useful for limited-profile devices, such as PDAs and mobile phones"?

It is mainly use for public apis it depends on which approach you want to use.

> What does it mean by "JAX-RS do not require XML messages or WSDL service–API definitions?

It has its own standards WADL(Web application Development Language) it has http request by which you can access resources they are altogether created by different mindset,In case in Jax-Rs you have to think of exposing resources

Answer (score -1):

i have been working on Apachi Axis1.1 and Axis2.0 and JAX-WS but i would suggest you must JAX-WS because it allow you make wsdl in any format , i was making operation as GetInquiry() in Apache Axis2 it did not allow me to Start Operation name in Upper Case , so i find it not good , so i would suggest you must use JAX-WS