# If I use the WCF services with JSON return then what will be the advantage and disadvantage over web API

Tags: c#

If I use the WCF services with JSON return then what will be the advantage and disadvantage over web API?

Thanks.

Comment: You should specify your case, maybe show us some sourcecode and then we could help you. If not, you are just asking for a subjective answer. Which you should avoid to do. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357806/rest-vs-wcf-pros-and-cons