# Web services architecture/information flow

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I have just started learning about Web Services. These are my understandings on a very high level based on whatever I have gone through:

1.The Service Provider/Server creates the WebService and the Service description (WSDL) is created which is **published** on the url/registry.

2.The Service Requestor/Client **searches** for the Web Service in the registry/url and obtains the WSDL which contains the **binding** informations

3.The Service Requestor uses this information to interact with the Service Provider using SOAP/HTTP, which **invokes** the Web Service.

I would like to know whether this is the basic architecture of web-services? If not, what is?

Comment: You are refering to http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/#engaging right? In that case: Yes, you are describing a basic scenario that conforms to this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is almost correct, however:

> 1.The Service Provider/Server creates the WebService and the Service description (WSDL) is created which is published on the url/registry.

The better approach is first to create WSDL and then generate Web service and client from it. It helps when you're dealing with heterogeneous platforms (PHP, Java and .NET are best example) because when you generate WSDL from the service, each of these platforms has its own way of doing it. Trust me on this one :)

> 3.The Service Requestor uses this information to interact with the Service Provider using SOAP/HTTP, which invokes the Web Service.

True if we are talking about SOAP Web services, but there are also REST Web services which are being used more and more, so take a look at them also:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap)