# How to send data between java and php

Tags: java, php, connection

I'm programming a homepage and I need to connect to JAVA and send some encrypted information to java and getting some back. How should I do this?

Comment: you need to connect to JAVA?? That doesnt make sense ..

Comment: what do you mean with "I need to connect to JAVA"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give you an idea

1. compile and build your JAVA program, and your program should accept command line arguments as input and write output to STDOUT (i.e. write to `System.out` using `System.out.print` and such.)
2. Then, in PHP, use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute that jar file.

Comment: I think you mean `System.out`. Java != C. Still +1

Comment: I somehow assume that the OA knows output to STDOUT here means `System.out` >.<

Comment: Yeah, but that you and I do know that doesn't necessarily mean every beginning or amateur programmer who reads this knows that.

Comment: Anyway, just fixed up the answer. :)

Comment: Noticed that. But you have my upvote already.

Answer (score 3):

Check out PHP's [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command.

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

It allows you to issue commands to the shell (such as a call to a Java program, etc.) and return results back to PHP.

Comment: How to make it work ?

Comment: You cannot return any value of String from the jar that you make

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: I assume you mean that you want to connect a PHP or Java
>   Website to a PHP or Java Server.

Usually when to alien systems have to communicate to each other in a web context - "webservices" come in play. There you can use a SSL encrypted connection to send and receive messages/data.

The two Buzzwords you can investigate reading are `REST` and `SOAP`.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap
```