# How pass method to PHPStorm 6 REST Client Windows Tools

Tags: phpstorm

Hi (Sorry for my english),

I would be use the new tools windows : REST Client in PHPStorm 6, but i have a little problem.

I write my soap url and it's ok, i retrieve the xml response (look at [Heberger image http://img15.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_529269screen1.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=529269screen1.png)).
After that i want call the method : login but i don't see how that work, how pass this method to the rest api. (look at [Heberger image http://img15.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_696499screen2.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=696499screen2.png))

And the xml response was :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>Sender</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Thank you for your response (and correction on my bad english :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging the response your service uses SOAP, why this client is tailored for REST. Take a look at [Representational state transfer (REST) and Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap) to get the difference.

Basically to perform the request you need to provide a properly formatted request body (which may be quite elaborate).