# SOA technology choice for Java Developer

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, soap, soa

I am a newbie Java EE 6 Developer (EJB 3.1 ; JPA 2.0 ; JSF 2.0; etc..).
I want to start learning SOA using Java. I found 2 ways:

- SOAP: which is complicated and boring to learn; the only strong point: is the UDDI/WSDL listing
- REST: easy to learn & to deploy; many strong points : performance, security, speed...

My question: What the market needs now? 
 SOAP or REST? If I choose REST, it will be the right choice ??

Comment: Market needs both. Start learning REST, then follow with SOAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend a lot on your business area. For fast moving technology areas such as back end for mobile phone apps, ticket systems, anything Google or areas where you have most of the control yourself - REST is probably the best choice, but if you work with business areas that changes technology slower, SOAP is still dominant and will be for a very long time. Examples are banking, medicine etc. It is often the same areas that get a lot of value out of the strict WSDL design.

it is no "right" choice, it depends on what you are working with, and what kind of systems you plan to integrate with. That being said, REST is probably the architecture for the future.

to get more information, read this:
[Representational state transfer (REST) and Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap)