# When does SOAP make more sense than REST?

Tags: rest, soap

From my understanding of REST, the implicit assumption is that all operations are CRUD operations.  Sometimes, you are not doing CRUD operations and are doing some more complex logic.  In this case, is not SOAP more suitable?  Or is it the case that all operations no matter how complex are a series of CRUD operations so they should be split up into a set of smaller CRUD operations to be called one after the other?  But, does this not make the operation you are attempting more cumbersome to write?  I am trying to understand when it might make more sense to use SOAP instead of REST.

Comment: This question perhaps belong better to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap this has some good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm working in banking area. the one of the biggest bank in Russia.
we using soa and we have a lot of webservices.
we like that, because:

> 1. it's simple to decompose one task -> one service
> 2. it's simple to manage webservices([Service Orchestration vs. Service Choreography](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnreynolds/archive/2006/01/service_orchest.html))
> 3. it's pretty simple to localize a bugs because you have to rewrite only one service and you do't need to rewrite all logic(in rest we
>      will rewrite all logic if bug has been found)
> 4. it's simple to create a map of organisation if we use soap webservices(after we could join webservices together and get another logical unit)