# Representational state transfer and Simple Object Access Protocol (ANDROID)

Tags: android, xml, json, rest, soap

Ok i am not sure if this question has been asked before on SO.. I am confused with SOAP and REST.. I know that SOAP is formatted in XML and is send over HTTP whereas REST can be send over XML, JSON etc.. [Representational state transfer (REST) and Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/representational-state-transfer-rest-and-simple-object-access-protocol-soap) makes a pretty good point. 
But does that mean that SOAP cannot be send using JSON????..
I am asking the above question in reference to android.
I know this is a pretty stupid question, but i am really confused on this one.
Any help is appreciated!!...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But does that mean that SOAP cannot be send using JSON?

Correct. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP):

> SOAP, originally defined as Simple Object Access Protocol, is a protocol specification for exchanging structured information in the implementation of Web Services in computer networks. It relies on XML Information Set for its message format...

And note that this has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 1):

Actually SOAP or Simple Object Access Protocol is an envelop format for exchanging WebService request and response information. REST is a special kind of WebService that must be designed with a set of constraints. For example in a RESTful WebService method information must be placed in the HTTP method and scoping information must be placed in the URI.
For understanding the architecture of web services and for a good introduction to RESTful web services i highly recommend you to read the following book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Restful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)