# How to pass an Url link to a Website using Soap

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap

I want to pass a youtube url link to a website because My app will send the youtube link to a website called http://www.clipconverter.cc then I will convert the youtube link to download video and I need to get the downloaded video date in my app.

Is that Possible in soap concept

Please Help will be appreciated

I have seen some coding for soap but not fully understand I will mention it bellow please help me regarding this.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         " <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.listentoyoutube.com/\">\n"
                         "<>%@</>\n"
                         "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n" ,txtfld.text];
```

Comment: Maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20022421/6124910