# Main differences between SOAP and RESTFUL and Which one is suitable for Native mobile applications?

Tags: android, mobile, windows-mobile, titanium-mobile

We are planning to develop a *Cross Platform mobile application* which supports native language.
And in my project we need to consume/create services, So which one is suitable ? SOAP  or RESTFUL. (using **Xmarin** development Tools )

Answer (score 2):

SOAP protocol is an XML message that describes messaging between the client and the server. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

REST service are much more simple and somewhat intuitive as it embraces the http protocol and is entirely web based. You can send and receive data as JSON, XML or even plain text. It's light weighted compared to SOAP. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

For a mobile application I would use restful service - first because it's much more lightweight, the size of the message is smaller, you can easily implement it in Titanium with the httpclient. For a SOAP you'll need to wither parse the XML yourself according to the protocol, or find a library that does it for you (I bet there are some JS libraries out there that do that).

Also have a look at this post over here: [Representational state transfer (REST) and Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/representational-state-transfer-rest-and-simple-object-access-protocol-soap)

and this article:
http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/tip/REST-vs-SOAP-How-to-choose-the-best-Web-service