# REST an architecture but SOAP a protocol?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, architecture, protocols

I was trying to figure out REST VS SOAP where some folks says

> REST is an architecture, SOAP is a protocol.

But i did not get (any where on net) what makes Rest an architecture but SOAP as protocol ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOAP vs REST (differences)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Representational state transfer (REST) and Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/representational-state-transfer-rest-and-simple-object-access-protocol-soap)

Comment: REST does not define a protocol, it uses mostly HTTP, while SOAP does.