# What is the difference between SOAP and REST webservices? Can SOAP be RESTful?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, soap

From MSDN magazine https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942839.aspx
I understand that

When RESTful endpoints are asked for data using HTTP, the HTTP verb used is GET.

Using REST means that you can take advantage of HTTP caching and other features, like Conditional GET, that aid in scaling services. Many of these techniques can't be used with SOAP because SOAP uses POST only over HTTP.

From the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

RESTful systems typically, but not always, communicate over the Hypertext Transfer Protocol with the same HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) used by web browsers to retrieve web pages and send data to remote servers.[

But **will it be a violation of REST architecture to use HTTP POST to get data from a resource**? 
In other words, can a SOAP based webservice be RESTful?

Are there any other differences between RESTful and SOAP based webservice?

Comment: [This](http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest) is a good read on the topic, as well as [this](http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/). Basically, `SOAP` does not *truly* rely on `HTTP`, that just happens to be the most common medium it's implemented over. Because `REST` uses the `HTTP` verbs, it requires the `HTTP` protocol. By definition, `SOAP` and `REST` are mutually exclusive: `REST` uses the `HTTP` path and query to access objects, `SOAP` uses messages.

Comment: @EBrown REST typically uses http its not mandatory. That's what I believe. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `REST` requires use of the `HTTP` verbs to operate, which binds it to be an `HTTP-based` service. `RESTful` services, on the other-hand, are different. That's like saying `Cat` and `Cat-like` animals. Yes, both terms have the word `Cat` in them, but they refer to different things.

Comment: @EBrown So can a SOAP based websaervice also be RESTful?

Comment: @EBrown can we simply use http POST like SOAP  to get data. Can we call it as RESTful? If not, then why?

Comment: Not by definition. Recall that `SOAP-based` services exchange messages over *any medium.* This is why `HTTP-based SOAP` services use `POST` requests: they **must** maintain the ability to send larger messages over the established medium. `GET` requests have a very strict upper-bound on data size. (And it's quite small - larger `SOAP` messages would never get through.) You *can* use `HTTP POST` to get the data, but it's not a `RESTful` service then, as the `HTTP verb` has no meaning. `RESTful` services are `RESTful` because the verb indicates the action.

Comment: @EBrown I request you to post an answer. I understand the reason why you choose to post a comment instead. But your comment explains it better than below answers. " You can use HTTP POST to get the data, but it's not a RESTful service then, as the HTTP verb has no meaning. RESTful services are RESTful because the verb indicates the action." I would like to give you the credit.

Comment: I am adding an answer, with great detail. :)

Comment: Also, I would recommend editing the title: "What is the difference between **SOAP** and **REST** webservices, can **SOAP** be **RESTful**?" to help future readers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Introduction

I'm posting this as an answer because comments just don't suffice. Here is what I want to summarize for you.

First, we'll start with these two references:

http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest

http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/

Lastly, I want to start this post off by saying the following:

**SOAP** and **REST** were both designed to solve the following problem: how do two *disparate* applications, programmes or devices interchange and share data between each other, in an extensible and easily-understood manner?

---

## RESTful Services

*By design* **RESTful** (**Re**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer) services use `HTTP` and the `HTTP` verbs (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) to indicate intent. These verbs *very clearly* indicate to the user what is going to happen when they are used. The server can use them to make *preemptive* decisions. That is, it can make a decision *long before* the action is ready to take place.

Consider this, you have to access a small bit of data from a users **Insert Service** account. Which is easier, a `GET endpoint/users/account/id` request, or a `POST endpoint/users/account` request that has a body of `id`? By definition of **REST**, the `POST` request violates the basic agreement that **REST** implies. That is: *the server is expected to know, before the data has arrived, what intentions with it the user has.* This is the basic fundamental that **REST** attempts to guarantee.

This fact, no, this fundamental, mandates that **RESTful** communication be permitted to indicate what intention the client has before the client begins to send data. This allows the server to *accept and reject* messages long before they arrive, thus reducing processing load.

Another aspect of **REST** (especially with the **Twitter**, **Facebook** and **Google** APIs): **RESTful** services, with the focus and mandate on `HTTP`, can take advantage of `HTTP` response headers. That is, they may respond with an `HTTP 403 Forbidden` message if the client is not permitted access. **SOAP-based** services may not. The resulting message must indicate such a result.

**RESTful** services tend to associate `HTTP verbs` (or actions) with nouns (or entities/objects.) Generally speaking, plurality and singularity imply more about the action. I.e. `GET RootEndpoint/Employees` would be expected to return **all** employees (or at least a large group matching a specific criteria.) Whereas `GET RootEndpoint/Employee/12` would be expected to return **only one** employee. (Generally, Employee with ID 12.)

**RESTful** services make a *direct correlation* between the `HTTP verb` (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) and the *action.* This is the purpose of the tie between the two: there is nothing special that needs added to the message body to indicate *what the user intends to do.* (I'll continue to stress this point throughout.)

**REST** was designed entirely for `HTTP`. And it is **very** good at it's job.

### RESTful Filtering

Generally speaking, to filter `REST` service requests you would include multiple URL segments with each segment indicating what parameter follows it.

I'll take an example from the Spotify API: `https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlist/`:

> ### Get a Playlist
>
> Get a playlist owned by a Spotify user.
>
> #### Endpoint
>
> ```
> GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}
> ```
>
> ### Request Parameters
>
> ```
> +---------------------------------------------------+
> | Path parameter | Value                            |
> +---------------------------------------------------+
> | user_id        | The user's Spotify user ID.      |
> | playlist_id    | The Spotify ID for the playlist. |
> +---------------------------------------------------+
> ```

In that API endpoint, you specify that you are looking for a `users` object with `user_id` of `{user_id}`, and a `playlists` object (within that `users` object) with the `playlist_id` of `{playlist_id}`.

Some RESTful services allow combination flags on parameters.

Take the Stack Exchange API, for example. You can fetch multiple questions or answers by separating them with semicolons, and it will essentially filter to just those questions or answers.

If we analyze [this endpoint (/questions/{ids}/answers)](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions), you'll see that it specifies:

> Gets the answers to a set of questions identified in id.
>
> This method is most useful if you have a set of interesting questions, and you wish to obtain all of their answers at once or if you are polling for new or updates answers (in conjunction with sort=activity).
>
> `{ids}` can contain up to 100 semicolon delimited ids, to find ids programatically look for `question_id` on question objects.
>
> The sorts accepted by this method operate on the follow fields of the answer object:

This is also a good example of an API that allows additional `GET` requests to filter/sort the results even further.

Example of usage: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30581530/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow`

Now, if we do the same with the [/answers/{ids} endpoint](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids), we can come up with something along the lines of: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/30582379;30581997;30581789;30581628?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow`. This pulls the four specified answers for us.

We can combine even more, for example, with the SE API and include filters to restrict the fields returned: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30581530/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!)V)P2Uyugvm`. (See [this link to /2.2/filters](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/filters/!%29V%29P2Uyugvm) for an explanation of that `filter` parameter.)

---

## SOAP-based Services

Enter **SOAP** (**S**imple **O**bject **A**ccess **P**rotocol), which was the predecessor to **REST**. **SOAP** solved this problem by sending messages back and forth. They use `XML` (though you could build a **SOAP-based** service without it, similarly to being able to build a **RESTful** service without `JSON`) to exchange a message, whereby the server has *no initial indication* of what to do.

**SOAP-based** services solve this issue in a manner that is agnostic of transport medium. The server and client need not use `HTTP`, or even `TCP` at all. They just need to use *the same, or compatible* transport mediums. In fact, you could think of the modern-day corporate environment as a **SOAP-based** service. When you need to get new supplies, you put in a *requisition* to your office manager, who then responds with a message. Upon receiving the initial requisition, your manager has *no idea* if it is permitted or not. They have to read the rest of the requisition in order to determine whether it is a valid request or if it is invalid.

**SOAP** was designed around `RPCs` (Remote-Procedure Calls), many firewalls block these. So, as a result, **SOAP** was modified to work over `HTTP`. It was designed to integrate *vastly different* technologies.

Because **SOAP** is designed around messages, it is a *much* more verbose service. It is generally easier to represent *compound actions* in **SOAP** services. That is to say, if you are requesting `objects` based on **many** criteria (instead of just one) **SOAP** tends to have better interface for this.

### SOAP-based Filtering

SOAP-based services filter with additional fields in the RPC. How these fields are combined is up to the provider.

I'll take an example from the Global Weather API: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather:

> ### GetWeather
>
> Get weather report for all major cities around the world.
>
> #### Test
>
> To test the operation using the HTTP POST protocol, click the 'Invoke' button.
>
> ```
> +---------------------------------------------------+
> | Parameter      | Value                            |
> +---------------------------------------------------+
> | CityName:      |                                  |
> | CountryName:   |                                  |
> +---------------------------------------------------+
> ```

If you specify, for example, "Blanding" and "United States" you will see the generated XML looks like the following:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>   <soap12:Body>
>     <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
>       <CityName>Blanding</CityName>
>       <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
>     </GetWeather>
>   </soap12:Body>
> </soap12:Envelope>
> ```

This would be submitted (for an HTTP SOAP request) as a POST-based call to `http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather`.

---

Back to the original question:

## Can a SOAP-based webservice be RESTful?

This was your original question, and I believe it stands to reason that it cannot, based on the information I have provided. These two services are *mutually-exclusive.* **REST** intends to solve the issue with the exchange of `headers` that indicate intent, and `message bodies` that indicate purpose. **SOAP** intends to solve the issue with the exchange of `messages` that indicate intent and purpose.

**Will it be a violation of REST architecture to use HTTP POST to get data from a resource?** Yes. The **RESTful** service architecture is designed to use the term `POST` to represent a *specific action.* Each `HTTP verb` in **REST** represents *what that action* intends to do.

As I said in the comments on the initial question:

> You can use `HTTP POST` to get the data, but it's not a **RESTful** service then, as the `HTTP verb` has no meaning. **RESTful** services are **RESTful** because the *verb* indicates the *action*.

---

## What do I choose, SOAP or REST?

This part exists primarily for future readers.

Both protocols have advantages and disadvantages, and you should choose which protocol you are using based on the requirements of the problem. Instructing you on how to accomplish that is beyond the scope of this question and answer. That said, there are three things to consider: *know your project*, *know your requirements*, and most of all, *correctly document it for your audience.*

Comment: What do you mean by the words intent and purpose, in terms of webservices?

Comment: Intent describes what *you are trying to accomplish.* I.e., when you send an `HTTP GET` request through **REST**, you indicate that your **intent** is to retrieve data. Purpose describes the actual *implementation* or *data.* The **purpose** of an `HTTP GET` is to describe my **intent** to retrieve data. I might need to make some edits to clear them up.

Comment: I assume that in GetEmployees/12 request, GET is intent and 12 is purpose. How about PutEmployees/12  or DeleteEmployees/12 request? Is PUT intent or is PUT/12 intent and details of 12 purpose? And how about the purpose of GetAllEmployees/ ? I am assuming DELETE and PUT behave the same.

Comment: @user2330678 In the first case: `GET Employee/12` would be the most accepted form, and the intent is to `GET` *some data.* The purpose is to `GET Employee number 12`. *Intent* describes the broader goal. *Purpose* describes what exactly you are doing. There are 4 intents in **REST**: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`.

Comment: @user2330678 That is to say, **REST** associates plurality and singularity literally. `GET Employees` would return all (or many) `Employee` objects. Whereas `GET Employee/12` would return one `Employee` object. And with **SOAP** services, because they are *message-based*, they can represent *compound actions* easier. (Filtering by multiple criteria, for example.)

Comment: It would  be nice if you can give an example url of filtering by multiple criteria for a soap based and a restful webservics

Comment: @user2330678 I can add something about it, I'm sure. :)

Comment: StackExchange's RESTful API allows to fetch multiple users, questions and answers by separating each ID with a semicollon (`;`). Using the API call https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30581530/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow will retrieve the answers on this question. Using https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30581530/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!)V)P2Uyugvm will give only the IDs. (continue...)

Comment: Now, you add a semicollon between each ID and call this: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/30582379%3B30581997%3B30581789%3B30581628?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow and it will retrieve everything about the answers in this question.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: @EBrown It should be in the answer since the beggining. So, take your time. After that, expect plenty of upvotes. Notice that I tweaked the comment a tiny bit.

Comment: The filtered link is broken, on the last example

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Fixed it, the filter had a parenthesis in it that broke Markdown.

Comment: @EBrown Thanks. Can't upvote your answer since I have marked as an answer. How would the SOAP uri look like for (/questions/{ids}/answers)?

Comment: It wouldn't be a URI like that, you would submit the RPC to `http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather` for the example I posted. Where the `POST` body is the RPC call.

Answer (score 2):

REST uses the HTTP verbs to articulate what action you are trying to accomplish.

A "GET" request is asking the service to return the item at a location.

A "POST" request is asking the service to create a new entity at a location (which will probably get persisted to a DB behind the scenes).

A "PUT" request is asking the service to update an existing entity at a location.

A "DELETE" request is asking the service to remove an existing entity at a location.

So no, you can't really use "POST" for something like a "GET" and still call yourself a REST API. Your consumers will be really confused by that.

Comment: from wiki page, "RESTful systems typically, but not always, communicate over the Hypertext Transfer Protocol with the same HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) used by web browsers to retrieve web pages and send data to remote servers." So, isn't it possible to use POST for all operations?

Comment: Anything is possible, you can write it anyway you want. You can make "DELETES" create new records and "GETS" delete records if you want to. But you are going to confuse your consumer. So, just stick to the convention that everyone else understands. That's why REST is popular. It is understood by convention.

Comment: @user2330678 Yes it is possible to use all POST's for a RESTful service (and I have come across some that do exactly that) and they still are RESTful services.  However unless there is a very good reason, it is best to stick with the conventions that have been established.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, the services are very different.

SOAP is about remote procedure calls (RPC) which means it is designed to call methods remotely. A proxy of the server methods on the client has to stay in sync with the server. WSDL is commonly used to keep the models in sync.

SOAP also disregards a lot of HTTP features. As you mentioned, it uses POST methods for everything. It also wraps data in a proprietary XML data format.

REST uses URLs to reference resources. The resource representation can be in any format (json, xml, csv, binary,...) and can take advantage of HTTP content negotiation (Accept* headers). HTTP methods map to CRUD methods very well.

True REST services must use a data format that is hypermedia driven (HAL, JSON collection, ... or vendor custom). It provides an ability to discover links to associated resources from a single fixed URL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS

I do not see how the same service (a single contract) can meet all that criteria.