# can ASMX web services be made REST api's?

Tags: c#, rest, soap, asmx

so i have read that SOAP uses HTTP and ASMX web services uses SOAP, so why ASMX web services are not compatible with rest?

i have a ASMX web service wich contains a method, is it possible to call this method using REST API style?

Comment: Because apples and oranges.  It's basically the same as asking "can a car be made into a carpet?  After all, it's just three more letters."

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to make your service expose non soap actions or do you want to manually handle all the soap by hand when making calls to the service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between SOAP and REST webservices? Can SOAP be RESTful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581530/what-is-the-difference-between-soap-and-rest-webservices-can-soap-be-restful)

Answer (score 2):

you can get close to REST by using get/post verbs, but imo the best thing about REST is human readable json, and you cannot achieve that with asmx.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more complicated than that. SOAP Web-Services abstracts the HTTP requests doing exchanges of XML point-to-point. You call the webmethod and get an result, always an XML response. You don't have to worry about if it's a PUT or GET request - or if the appropriate request verb is POST.

In REST, you work near the http level. You return results based on url queries for parameters in GET or PUT requests; POST request you can embed json text in request body (which is very common on ASP Net Core Web API).
If you want an json response of an user profile, you create an http GET request for `http://myserver.com/user/{UserId}`. You can even do that from the browser address bar.

Considering an simple operation like returning an zip file in SOAP means that zip file will need to be encoded before embedded in the SOAP XML response. In REST you simply send the byte stream flagging the http response with ContentType = application/zip.
No SOAP envelope, no encoding, no embedding in XML.

DISCLAIMER: if it appears oversimplified, it's intentional.