# How to find if a webpage uses REST or SOAP web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

Is there a way to find out if a webpage uses REST or SOAP web services in it's back-end? If there is a way then what is it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the network requests using a browsers developer tools.

Checking the headers for `text/xml`and a SOAP envelope might indicate SOAP

If its using REST you can check to see the header method is using GET, PUT, POST, DELETE with `application/json` which might indicate REST

SEE:

- [How can I debug a HTTP POST in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome)

And an in depth explanation of what I mean by "might be":

- [Representational state transfer (REST) and Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/representational-state-transfer-rest-and-simple-object-access-protocol-soap)