# Web Service for Android app. More important security. SOAP o REST?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, soap

I need to implement a Web Service for Android App. Security is more important than other thing. What is more recomendable, SOAP or REST ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion securing your API has no connection to what you're serving up beneath it. You can secure it with OAuth, your own two-step auth, simple API tokens - however you please.

My personal preference is REST-ful APIs that understand JSON. XML, if need be. SOAP is very versatile, but I find it extremely cumbersome to setup and consume.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be helpful : [Secure Web Services: REST over HTTPS vs SOAP + WS-Security. Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853620/secure-web-services-rest-over-https-vs-soap-ws-security-which-is-better)

On a side note, at least for me, REST is a better choice in terms of coding and response times.