# Encrypting exchanged data in a RESTful

Tags: java, web-services, security, rest

I have created a `Restfull` `web-service` in `java` that is consumed by an `android application`. The work is almost done.

Now I feel the need to secure my `web-service`. I don't want to send a `login` and `password` for that purpose, because I'm already asking the user for it, and testing whether he exists in my `database` or not. What I want is to `encrypt` exchanged data.

Do you have any idea how can I integrate that ?

Comment: Do you really need to encrypt the data at a higher layer or is it sufficient to use ssl/tls in the first place? I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: I need basic security. I think SSL/TLS would be sufficient. But I really don't know where to start from! I have no experience with security! Can you recommend me a tutorial or whatever ... ? Thanks for the feedback !!

Comment: I agree with @Fildor.  If you use SSL, then your transmission will be secured with a standard, easy to use, and widely supported method.  If you try to one-off, then you have to worry about either storing a key in the app, which risks getting deciphered over time, or coming up with some way to exchange keys, which is basically what SSL is doing.

Comment: @ashabasa, Most of the steps depend on what web server you are using.

Comment: Can you tell us what server you are using?

Comment: Use SSL.  Otherwise you'd need to encrypt/decrypt individual files on each end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853620/secure-web-services-rest-over-https-vs-soap-ws-security-which-is-better

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat server. And I'm developing the web service with Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use HTTPS for your need. SSL/TLS provide better encryption decryption over https. And you don't need to reinvent wheels for this basic purpose. 
If you are using tomcat to host REST web serivces then [here is a simple tutorial to turn on SSL in tocamt](http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes)

look at this [one also](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)

Comment: After Configuring Tomcat To Support SSL Or Https. Is there any code to write ... ?

Comment: So basicly, the steps I need to follow are this tutorial :http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/ to configure SSL in my Tomcat, then call the web service using https in stead of http??