# Is RESTful web service secured enough for Banking applications?

Tags: spring, rest, soap, spring-security, ws-security

I'm going to develop a Banking application that will send and receive information to mobile devices of bank account holder. I want to use REST api of Spring framework for this purpose. Is there any bank that uses RESTful api for applications? 
Does RESTful api provide enough security for this purpose? 
Or should I stick to use SOAP web service? 
I know, this question is asked several times. But I want to concentrate on feasibility of REST api for Banking domain.

Comment: Security has nothing to do with REST or SOAP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is as secure (or insecure) as any other method including SOAP. You still have to follow all best practices while writing your application (using https everywhere, encrypting sensitive data, making sure you don't write sensitive data to logs in plain text, and so on). It is best to discuss with the Security team for your bank/company, they'll usually have a set of requirements that you need to follow to secure your application.

Answer (score 2):

Most banks still use SOAP for integration, but you could find examples of companies like Visa or Paypal which expose their api in a RESTful way.

There is a key difference between using SOAP with WS-Security and a REST api with SSL, thats [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) which offers end-to-end security (offers confidentiality and integrity protection from the source of the message to the receiver).

What we are dealing here is security at two different levels: HTTPS applies at the transport layer (which you could apply to REST or SOAP service) and WS-Security applies at the application layer.

But now you could deal with REST using [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/), check on how Paypal uses it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/).

Another question related: [Secure Web Services: REST over HTTPS vs SOAP + WS-Security. Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853620/secure-web-services-rest-over-https-vs-soap-ws-security-which-is-better)

Answer (score 0):

**From security perspective REST over HTTPS is good enough unless you need end-to-end security or you have compliance limitations.**

If your banking mobile application will communicate through any intermediates (this could be NFC, Bluetooth Low Energy enabled POS e.g.) then I would recommend considering end-to-end security depending on risks and sensitivity of the information you are planning to send. Unfortunately there is no end-to-end security mechanism I can recommend for banking app except WS-Security. I had a look at many solutions like  [JSON Web Encryption (JWE)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption-40), [Javascript Object Signing and Encryption (JOSE)](http://jose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [OAuth 1.0 Signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) and others. I've found no solution which provides end-to-end security with respect to Integrity, Confidentiality, Authenticity for RESTful web-services out-of-the-box. The reason is that RESTful web-services are assumed to work always over HTTP and thus they will be protected with HTTPS. So if you need end-to-end security it's a good point to think about SOAP and WS-Security.

Another reason to think on WS-Security could be compliance regulations like PCI DSS. Then you can reduce compliance scope with end-to-end encryption of cardholder data. Good example is what Netflix guys did https://youtu.be/sYFDnGjNVrk. So investigate your compliance regulation if you have such before making a decision.