# Understanding SOAP vs REST from an authentication point of view

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

So I have currently been assigned to read about Web Services. I was going through the differences between REST, XML-RPC and SOAP and came across this particular link :

[REST vs XML-RPC vs SOAP](http://maxivak.com/rest-vs-xml-rpc-vs-soap/)

It mentions this following, in terms of authentication and authorization

> As for authentication and authorization, SOAP places the burden in the hands of the application developer. The REST methodology instead takes into account the fact that Web servers already have support for these tasks. Through the use of industry-standard certificates and a common identity management system, such as an LDAP server, developers can make the network layer do all the heavy lifting.

I was not able to understand this particular reference. Can some one explain how this happens in detail?

Comment: The article  referenced is poorly written. Suggest other sources of information: [SOAP or REST for Web Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services?rq=1) and [Secure Web Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853620/secure-web-services-rest-over-https-vs-soap-ws-security-which-is-better?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the links. The second one was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web service is method or mechanism to communicate between different applications using open standard such as XML, WSDL, and SOAP. Using web service different device or program communicates over network

Type of WebService

SOAP Web Service
RESTFul Web Service

more information you can check :http://entityclass.in/rest/home.htm

Comment: Please see the question carefully. I am not asking about what web services are.