# Contacts data transfer

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, soap

I'm developing android client which is capable of **upload** system db contacts information (name, phone_number, email).

Could someone suggest the best technology in point of best performance (in client) with about 1000 contacts.

SOAP or REST, XML or JSON.

Comment: see this answer it lists advantages of using REST over JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266466/why-prefer-rest-over-soap

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a REST service, as it is more lightweight as SOAP. Also, you don't need a stateful service for this. Next to that I would use JSON, for two reason. Almost always smaller than xml, and great Android support for parsers.