# How to handle complex availability of information in OOP from a RESTful API

Tags: objective-c, oop, api, language-agnostic, rest

My issue is that I'm dealing with a RESTful API that returns information about objects, and when writing classes to represent them, I'm not sure how best to handle all the possibilities of the status of each variable's availability. From what I can tell, there are 5 possibilities: The information

- is available
- has not been requested
- is currently being requested (asynchronously)
- is unavailable
- is not applicable

So with these, having an object represent its data with a value or null doesn't cut it. To give a more concrete example, I'm working with an API about the United States Congress, so the problem goes as thus:

I request information about a bill, and it contains a stub about the sponsoring legislator.
I eventually need to request all the information about that legislator. Not all the legislators will have all the information. Those in the House of Representatives won't have a senate class (Senators' six-year terms are staggered so a third expire every two years, the House is entirely re-elected every two years). Some won't have a twitter id, just because they don't have one. And, of course, if I have already requested information, I shouldn't try to request it again.

There's a couple options I see:

- I can create a Legislator object and fill it with what information I have, but then I have to have some mechanism of tracking information availability with the getters and setters. This is kind of what I'm doing right now, but it requires *a lot* of repeated code.
- I could create a separate class for abbreviated objects and replace them when I get more with immutable "complete" objects, but then I have to be really careful about replacing *all* references to them and also go through a bunch of hoops for unavailable, and especially, not applicable information.

So, I'm just wondering what other people's take on this issue is. Are there other (better?) ways of handling this complexity? What are the advantages and drawbacks of different approaches? What should I consider about what I'm trying to do in choosing an approach?

[Note: I'm working in Objective-C, but this isn't necessarily specific to that language.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat those remote resources as objects on the client side, the do yourself a huge favour and forget about the REST buzzword.  You will drive yourself crazy.  Just accept that you are doing HTTP RPC and move on as you would doing any other RPC project.

However, if you really want to do REST, you need to understand what is meant by the "State Transfer" part of the REST acronym and you need to read about HATEOAS.  It is a huge mental shift for building clients, but it does have a bunch of benefits.  But maybe you don't need those particular benefits.

What I do know, is if you are trying using a "REST API" to retrieve objects over the wire, you are going to come to the conclusion that REST is a [load of crap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285704/should-a-netflix-or-twitter-style-web-service-use-rest-or-soap).

Comment: Very much agreed.  That linked question (and your (accepted) answer to it) are excellent; your answer in particular is stellar.  I may excerpt from it to justify some decisions to my management...

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question, but I think you're probably overthinking this a bit.

Firstly, I think you're considering the possible states of information a bit too much; consider the more basic consideration that you either have the information or you don't.  WHY you have the information doesn't really matter, except in one case.  Let me explain; if the information about a certain bill or legislator or anything is not applicable, you shouldn't be requesting it / needing it.  That "state" is irrelevant.  Similarly, if the information is in the process of being requested, then it is simply not yet available; the only state you really care about is whether you have the information or if you do not yet have the information.

If you start worrying about further depths of the request process, you risk getting into a deep, endless cycle of managing state; has the information changed between when I got it and now?  All you can know about the information is if you've been told what it is.  This is fundamental to the REST process; you're getting REPRESENTATION of the underlying data, but there's no mistake about it; the representation is NOT the underlying data, any more than a congressman's name is the congressman himself.

Second, don't worry about information availability.  If an object has a subobject, when you query the object, query for the subobject.  If you get back data, great.  If you get back that the data isn't available, that too is a representation of the subobject's data; it's just a different representation than you were hoping for, but it's equally valid.  I'd represent that as an object with a null value; the object exists (was instantiated because it belonged to the parent), but you have no valid data about it (the representation returned was empty due to some reason; lack of availability, server down, data changed; whatever).

Finally, the real key here is that you need to be remembering that a RESTful structure is driven by hypermedia; a request to an object that does not return the full object's data should return an URI for requesting the subobject's data; and so forth.  The key here is that those structures aren't static, like your object structure seems to be hoping to treat them; they're dynamic, and it's up to the server to determine the representation (i.e., the interrelationship).  Attempting to define that in stone with a concrete object representation ahead of time means that you're dealing with the system in a way that REST was never meant to be dealt with.