# When to use SOAP for developing a web service

Tags: web-services

So, I have heard a lot of strong opinions on REST vs. SOAP here and in other forums. However, it seems SOAP developers aren't very vocal about their choices and hence I have rarely come across opinions to use SOAP.

So I am wondering if there's ever a reason to use SOAP over REST while developing a new web service or the goodness of REST architecture totally overwhelms SOAP in all scenarios

Comment: May want to check out this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest

Comment: I did and that's a contributing factor to this question. From the majority of the answers it seems the answer is ALWAYS REST and never SOAP. Many of the top voted answers actually don't give concrete reasons for prefering REST over SOAP. Apart from saying it is easier to do a REST service than SOAP. And the only advantage to SOAP seems to be better tools.

Comment: @Byron: I did looked at that discussion and it's a contributing factor to this question. From the majority of the answers it seems the answer is ALWAYS REST and never SOAP. Many of the top voted answers actually don't give concrete reasons for prefering REST over SOAP apart from saying it is easier to do a REST service than SOAP. And the only advantage to SOAP seems to be better tool support.

Comment: I am trying to find scenarios where it might be better to use SOAP over REST, i.e. where does SOAP makes sense over REST,  I am not looking to find advantages and disadvantages of both.

Comment: I think you need to read more carefully. For instance, '
 
down vote  It's nuanced.

If you need to have other systems interface with your services, than a lot of clients will be happier with SOAP, due to the layers of "verification" you have with the contracts, WSDL, and the SOAP standard." gives you some reasons to use SOAP.

Comment: here's a good article http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each/