# JSON response objects: "pretty" keys and larger response or short keys and smaller response?

Tags: javascript, json

My real-time web app makes ajax requests to obtain JSON econded data responses.

Returned data is usually in the form of an array of objects.

As the array has often a **lot** of elements (an although data sent is gzipped by the server) in order to keep the response size at minimum I'm keeping the **keys** in the response very short.

For example instead of using **description:** I use **d:**, instead of using **width:** I use **w:** and so on...

Doing so reduces the size of the response but, on the client side, very-short non human-readabe keys makes the JavaScript code (that access the object) less readable.

The only solution seem to reparse the response and rebuild the object with *pretty* keys or replace them in the original object received. But this may hurt the JavaScript code performance resulting in more delay...

**Exists a better solution?**

---

**EDIT:**

As **Björn Roberg** suggested in his comment I've made a comparison:

```
pretty-response.json       459,809 bytes
 short-response.json       245,881 bytes

pretty-response.json.zip    28,635 bytes
 short-response.json.zip    26,388 bytes
```

So as the response is compressed by the server the difference is really minimal.

Still, pretty response require the server to compress 450 KB of data, while short response just 240 KB.

Does this impact server performance (or is there a way to measure it) ?

Comment: Have you tried using "pretty" keys and compared the actual size of the transfer?

Comment: When you say you have a "lot" of data - how much are you talking? You can use [`redis`](http://redis.io/) to "outsource" the storing of JSON objects, which would help if you had a significant number of elements to process

Comment: I can't help but feel that, whatever your problem is, there must be a better solution than 450kb of JSON.

Comment: @lonesomeday despite it's unusual that's exactly the minimum data the web app needs to perform its task upon certain user actions.

Comment: @Paolo Sounds like a web app with a bad architecture.

Comment: @lonesomeday sounds like presumptuous (other than useless) as you don't know at all what the app does and how it does it.

Comment: @Paolo "Hit yourself on the head with a hammer" is bad advice. I can say this confidently, without knowing whether you intend to put up shelves or make a chocolate souffle. Seriously, any application that demands you transfer half a megabyte of JSON for client-side parsing is begging for a rethink.

Answer (score 9):

Since you are considering converting the short keys back to long keys on the client side, you are clearly concerned with the bandwidth requirements for the data and not the memory requirements on the client.

I've generated some files containing random data and three keys (description, something and somethingElse). I've also dumped the data through sed to replace those keys with d, s and e.

This results in:

```
750K   long-keys
457K   short-keys
```

HTTP has [support for compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression), and all significant clients support this with gzip. So, what happens if we gzip the files:

```
187K   10:26 long-keys.gz
179K   10:27 short-keys.gz
```

There is very little to choose between them, since gzip is rather good at compressing repeated strings.

So, just use HTTP compression and don't worry about munging the data.

gzip is also a really fast algorithm, so the impact it will have on server performance is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview?hl=es-ES&csw=1) and see if that makes any difference. It was developed to be faster and lighter than many other serialization formats (ie. XML and JSON).

Other formats exist that share the same goals, but protocol buffers, aka protobufs, are the one that sprang to my mind.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14029040/556770) for a nice comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decorator pattern to wrap the objects upon retrieval from the array.

However, given that you probably want to access all the objects returned (why would you return objects that aren't needed by the client?) it would probably be no slower, and possibly faster, to just convert the objects to objects with longer field names upon retrieval from the array.

If you are going to retrieve each object multiple times, you could even go through the array and replace them one by one, to avoid having to repeatedly convert them.

All these options have a performance cost, but it may not be significant. Profile!

Comment: Converting the obects to objects with longer field will do require processing a thus time on the client side. I'm ranging from 1,000 to 10,000 elements. As for profiling what's the actual cost it's hard because depends on the hardware/os/browser combination... Too many cases to test!

Comment: Do you really need to handle so many objects on one page? Can't you use lazy loading and/or do more processing on the server?

Comment: Yes I do. I know it's quite peculiar to have a response so big, but that's exactly the minimum data the web app need to perform its task upon certain user actions.

Answer (score 0):

compress your json from server with http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

library for compression http://dean.edwards.name/download/#packer

you can also check your json size by checking online if it reduce or not

Comment: the problem is the computational cost of -decompressing- it on the client side.

Comment: why not compress on serverside,i am sure it will help you out

Comment: I already compress server side and that makes the difference minimal. But now I wonder (as I don't know how to measure it) how big is on the server side the impact of compressing 450KB istead of just 250KB? (see my edit)

Comment: you can check the response time of server

Comment: the response time of the server is the sum of many things (variable each time) where the compression time is only one of them

Comment: but applying compress will add response time , so you can check how much incremented

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be readable and still use short keys, you could use index notation for accessing members:

```
var descriptionKey = 'd';
var widthKey = 'w';

//...

var description = yourObject[descriptionKey];
```