# Where shall I use protobuf

Tags: json, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

I was reading [this](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0) article about [protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) and I wondered where to use it in the projects. I read some articles that said google created protobuf to replace XML, but as far as I know in 2008 (the first release) JSON was already there.

I searched more and I found [an article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/06/05/choose-protocol-buffers/) that the writer suggested to use it instead of JSON, but I still don't get the idea completely.

So where shall I use it? Any special scenario, or like JSON whenever that I want to transport data? Any other scenarios?

Comment: I'd say any place you want to transmit, persist or otherwise serialize and deserialize data while minimizing its size and keeping it resilient to changes in the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful whenever you want to serialize/deserialize your data. Typical situations include sending your data to someone else over the network, storing it to disk or keeping it in context while performing asynchronous processes.

Here is a brief explanation about the main differences between protocol buffer, json and XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14029040/6681872