# Reasons for JSON data to be in an array?

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is probably a dumb question, but as I have not been programming for to long I wonder why I should send Json data in an array? The reason that I am asking is that I am building a simple jQuery form with Ajax callback (yes using json for simple things are unnecessary, but I want to learn how to use it). The script sends an id number to a php function, which depending on the id number can return one or more forms. So the question is why should I send the JSON data in an array?

Don´t know if it is important but here is the structure of the data being retuned.

```
foreach ($list as $row) {
  $out[] = ('<tr><td><a href="'.$row['link_form'].'">'.$row['name_form'].'</a></td>   <td>'.$row['date_added'].'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you use for your returned data should notionally match that of the data itself. So, if you are returning a list of things that have similar properties, you should use an array; if you are returning something which makes more sense to delineate into key-value pairs, return an object.

With JSON, you can nest these. So, for example, you could have an array of objects, which is a very common use-case. Say you are returning a DB table: each record could be an array element, which is an object that describes the fields.

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Joe Bloggs"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Jane Doe"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "I.P. Freely"}
]
```

Given that your objects are homogeneous in this case -- have the same key-value structure -- you *could* return an array of arrays, instead. Or, you could make things really generic and return an object that describes the table, then an array of arrays which ream out the content:

```
{
  "fields": [
              {"name": "id",   "type": "number"},
              {"name": "name", "type": "string"}
            ],
  "data":   [
              [1, "Joe Bloggs"],
              [2, "Jane Doe"],
              [3, "I.P. Freely"]
            ]
}
```

It's really up to you and the ultimate usage of the data.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is preferred over XML in AJAX because of several reasons. I hope this will be helpful.

[JSON and XML comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862310/json-and-xml-comparison)

Comment: I was more looking for an answer why I should have the JSON data in an array and not just send it? In the past I always put in an array, but I newer knew why. Now that I found Stackoverflow I have a place to ask dumb things you newer knew the answer to.