# JSON Parser Project

Tags: java, xml, json

I'm thinking about starting an open source JSON parser library in Java for fun and coding practice.  Would this be useful for people?  Would this have more adoption than an XML parser?

Comment: It is certainly easier to write, but the competition is fierce!

Comment: json is light weight, where as xml is little bit more confusing as json is key value concept...

Comment: JSON is already quite widely adopted. There are quite a few parser already existing. I think it can be indeed an interesting coding practice. (but there are already a lot of libraries, some being included in widely used frameworks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has always been a fair amount of backlash against XML, but this has really heated up since JSON became popular. A lot of people want to throw XML out the window and use JSON for everything, and for many problems, this is a reasonable thing to do. JSON and XML have many similar properties, but XML has some tricks up its sleeve that JSON can't yet match.  you can find more useful answer in the below [JSON and XML comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862310/json-and-xml-comparison) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json