# Json/XML use in WEBAPI for request and response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, xml

I am going to develop a WEBAPI in .NET and that will take a request in either XML or JSON so I am confused what is the best practice to use JSON or XML and what its advantage.It will be very helpful if I get any suggestions on this. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest JSON. 
JSON is lightweight. 
JSON format is text only can be read by any programming language.
Easy to understand. 
You can Check following link for detailed comparison.
[json-and-xml-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862310/json-and-xml-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

There are various comparisons available between XML and JSON
You can refer below links

[JSON and XML comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862310/json-and-xml-comparison)

http://blog.cloud-elements.com/json-better-xml

Other than this comparison, you can decide based upon who is the target consumer. If its open source, or for diverse consumer you can always provide both options.