# MySQL Json extract Vs Xml extract

Tags: mysql

We know MySQL 5.7 comes with built-in **JSON support** and  MySQL 5.1 & 5.5 was added  **XML support**.

But I want to understand performance wise which one is better Json extractor or XML extractor. Than I need to decide log data as XML or Json. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862310/json-and-xml-comparison) which discusses the performance of JSON and XML from the point of view of a browser parsing this content.  In general XML is bulkier than JSON.  I'm not sure this really matters from the point of view of logging.

Comment: Thanks Tim, data is limited around 10 to 20 fields but I want to know which is faster for extraction or retrieving data from MySQL.

Comment: If you follow the link I left above, for parsing JSON appears to be winning out over XML.  Again, this may be a moot point for the performance of your application.

Comment: that link is a discussion about xml vs json in general, but question asks specifically about their performance in MySQL, in which case, it would depend on their implementation in MySQL. I think best way would be to test it. shouldnt be too hard to throw a test rig together.