# In soap there is WSDL for communication but in rest what is there ?

Tags: rest, soap, restful-url, restful-architecture

In SOAP there is WSDL for communication. I read in blogs that WSDL 2.0 supports REST but it is not properly define the REST so is there any equivalent for REST ? I'm doing communication using JSON data between client and server so i need something that properly fit for communication so is there is something for this ?

Comment: You might want to look a the Atom publishing protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29

Answer (score 2):

There are different proposals in the industry, such as WADL (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language ), but unfortunately there is no commonly accepted REST metadata standard yet.

Answer (score 0):

In real WSDL can be used for REST but in reality it is not best fit for REST.

Comment: WSDL 2, CAN be used to describe REST though it is far from being wildly used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830581/rest-web-service-wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I would rather stay away from using WADL or any other descriptive languages, when it comes to REST style. RESTful services are fundamentally well-defined and self-descriptive in nature, hence the name Representational State Transfer. Given that they adhere  to the HTTP vocabulary (CRUD) and payload structure can be any character-set (raw, JSON, XML. etc.), there is no need for any standard descriptive language.

This is the fundamental shift from SOAP based services, where application developers need to worry about describing the service interfaces in WSDL for discovery and other purposes.