# Visual REST API playground

Tags: rest

What are some web apps that allow me to play with any REST APIs visually (by clicking) and also get some code generated (in any language) that captures what I have described visually?

Similar to Swagger or Google API Playground but allows me to talk to anything that speaks REST (assuming I have the proper auth credentials and I know what messages it understands).

Bonus points for something that can also "discover" what messages are understood, given a URL endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has 2 that I know of

1. [OData API explorer](http://services.odata.org/ODataAPIExplorer/ODataAPIExplorer.html)
2. [The data market service explorer](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/d11a9c01-19a1-419b-9858-a664a95a4347) (requires signing in, and then you can access free data sets)

Answer (score 2):

Considering that REST API's are going to follow their own conventions, terms, and have their own documentation (hopefully), this is an impossible problem. If you restrict your quest to visualizing API's that follow a "standard" form of self-documentation (see [REST web service WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830581/rest-web-service-wsdl) for some hopeful scenarios) you might be able to accomplish this.

Or you can use something like http://www.programmableweb.com/ to discover tutorials, tools, examples, and mashups of various existing APIs.

You could mock an API at http://apiary.io/.

You could explore and existing one through tools (e.g. [REST Console for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn))

What you can't have, is one-size-fits-all explorer for "every possible REST API." Some APIs follow conventions that others don't.

Answer (score 0):

[apigee](https://apigee.com/providers) and [apihub](http://www.apihub.com/) (now part of mulesoft) are two that I frequently visit. Of the two, apigee is my preferred provider.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that you're not going to see a lot of websites like this is because of the same-origin policy.  This means that you can't access a RESTful API located at `api.google.com` from a web app running at, say, `www.restfiddle.com` without sending all the API traffic through restfiddle.com's servers.  Sites like JSFiddle can exist (and are used widely) because all the processing is done on the client side.

Browser plugins, however, are exempt from the same-origin policy.  If you're using Chrome, try [**Postman**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm).  If your REST client doesn't need to be web-based, check out [**SoapUI**](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html).  **IntelliJ IDEA** has a nice REST client as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try Restlet Studio, it's the only visual API designer I've found, and seems pretty good, it imports and exports swagger & RAML.

http://studio.restlet.com/