# Restful Web Services generate rsdl document

Tags: java, web-services, rest, wsdl

I'm developing a restful web service app using Java. I want to generate a rsdl document like wsdl document into Soap WS. I read a lot of tutorial about wsdl, wadl  and rsdl but I couldn't find a tool to generate rsdl file from web service methos, params, annotations. As a last resort, I think of using Java's MyClass.Class methods. Is there any way to generate this description xml document? What is your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jersey, you'll want to look at using the WADL it can generate - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html
This is analagous to a SOAP WSDL although this is not really the intention with REST services, as you'll see in this related answer [REST web service WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830581/rest-web-service-wsdl?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Ross I could access wadl document by "application.wadl" paramter. I'm using my own rsdl document that generated by Java.Class definitions. It seems like wadl, I can change my structure in the future.Thanks for reply again.