# How to generate WADL for rest service written with fastapi python?

Tags: python, rest, wsdl, fastapi, wadl

The developer who will interact with my web service will require a wsdl. As I understand it, wsdl is for the soap service, and wadl for my rest service. The web service has already been written. How can I get/generate this file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST web service WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830581/rest-web-service-wsdl)

Comment: @EliasDorneles Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

So, you've just bumped the [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info) vs [SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/soap/info) conundrum. =)

There is no practical way to generate a WSDL description for a REST service.

But again, there is not really a good reason to do that, since they're consumed differently.

Your options are:

- explain to the developer who will use your web service that this is a REST service (and not SOAP)
- write a SOAP version of your service

In either case, you want to document and possibly give examples on how to consume the service. FastAPI already helps to do that with the `/docs` page, but you may need to better document how it's supposed to be used.

Good luck!

**Read more**

- [The `rest` tag wiki has useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info)