# Which web service to be chosen?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I have to develop a site like **paypal** which supports **online transaction** where i need to implement web service. In short , I need to build some **easy to use API** using web service.But i am really confused which one to chose from **REST or SOAP**.

***Java EE*** will be used to develop the web site. And our API will be mostly used for **GET , UPDATE (PUT in http verb)**

#### What i need :

- **Error handling ability:** A clear conception of ensuring the call has completed successfully or not . SOAP has it **built in** , but REST does not. It is a *must have* requirement for us.
- **Simplicity:**  As our API will be used by various clients it needs to have a relatively small learning curve. In this case REST will be a good fit. *A must have* attribute
- **Caching ability:** Caching will surely be a plus as it saves a lot of resources. SOAP does not support caching. It is a *good to have and high priority* requirement.
- **Human readable result:** It may be necessary for debugging purpose . But *not a must have* attribute.

Now which way i should go for at least fulfill the must have and high priority requirements which are:

- **Error handling abitliy**
- **Simpliciy**
- **Caching abitliy**

I have *googled a lot* but failed to come into a decision . If anybody can give me a **better suggestion other than these two** , you are most welcome. I **just need a solution which fulfill my requirement** that's all.

Some resources i found while googling:

- [SOAP vs REST](http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest/)
- [Choosing the right web service protocol](http://geeknizer.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol/)
- [When to use which web service](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each)

And my googling keywors were : SOAP vs REST , web service suitable for online transaction .

Comment: They're not mutually exclusive, a single webapp can support both. _However,_ a single client would probably only use one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP or REST for Web Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, use `REST`.

- It is so simple that you can even [explain it to your wife](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife)
- Allows [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13), caching is okey as long as RESTs concerns are addressed
- Human readable result for a decent limit
- Error handling is default, i mean every `protocol` should define it.

Comment: can you please give me any resource which shows that error handling ability is built in with REST?

Comment: from the `abstract` of the RFC `...through extension of its request methods, error codes and headers.` REST depends on HTTP's status code for sure. Again you must acknowledge that, REST cant `detect/find` error for you. It will `define what is an error`. If you wish to REST will find those erros, you need to improve your understanding more to what REST/SOAP/Protocol does. I believe you can understand.