# REST is built for the Web then what about SOAP?

Tags: java, rest, soap

I read an article where they are telling "REST is built for the Web". then what about SOAP? We also can not access SOAP web services without web.So I am confused.plz clarify what it means "REST is built for the Web", why they did not mentioned it for SOAP?

Below is the article link : http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-services-architecture

and section is "REST is built for the Web".

Comment: I read this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-services-architecture and this is the section they mentioned it "REST is built for the Web". Could u plz clarify me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is just an expression to add enthusiasm. It isn't to mean that
>   other existing web services architecture aren't build for the web.

Since REST is a choice implementation for a lot of lightweight(not much extra xml markup, human readable, no toolkits required to build) requirement, it has gotten a lot of traction in the past few years. Articles and papers reflect that enthusiasm by making statement that sound like **Universal Truth** but just know that they are trying to add a hint of enthusiasm. It also doesn't mean SOAP isn't used equally. SOAP is also built for the web.

They both have advantages and disadvantages. Other members on this site have given good accounts on the same. Here are good pointers on which one is used for what.

[Which Web Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269067/which-web-service-to-be-chosen)

[SOAP vs. REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences)

Answer (score 0):

REST and SOAP are different specifications.In SOAP Webservice all the request and response adheres to SOAP standard.YES its true that both have been used in the implementation of various components of Web as they run on a server(WebServer/Application Server) however they can be used in different scenerios.REST is light weight and stateless but SOAP is a bit heavy weight and can be stateful.You can try implementing a REST using Jersey and a SOAP webservice its better to implement both for better understanding. :)