# is restful get and httpget different from one another?

Tags: rest, http, get

I am totally new in this field.. May b my question is also vague.. But while searching i came across 2 different implementation.. One is [this](http://www.techferry.com/articles/RESTful-web-services-JAX-RS-annotations.html#GET)
and other is [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) , where httpget is used..

So are these same ? When we talk about Restful, is the 2nd implementation valid ?

Guide me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTful is a design pattern for web applications that expose a public interface.

It uses the HTTP protocol to send and receive data.

GET, POST,  PUT and DELETE are the operations that RESTful most commonly perform with that data.

All these operations are HTTP operations (but PUT and DELETE need more work. Check [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx) for details).

So, to cut a long story short, GET and HTTP GET are the same.

SO has a wealth of resources to get you started with RESTful. Understanding the [difference between SOAP and REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services/77018#77018) maybe a good starting point.