# which protocol is more convenient for transit tracking system SOAP or REST?

Tags: android, rest, soap

Real-time transit tracking is gaining popularity as a means for transit agencies to improve the rider experience. I want to implement a system where smartphones of riders will send automatically in the background data(location) to the server and the these data will send on request to another riders.
which is more convenient for transit tracking system SOAP or REST? Which one is easier to work with, more flexible?

Comment: both have the fans. the rest is a matter of opinion (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't natively support SOAP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/303500/3009199 so for an Android app you'd be better to use REST. 
That said every project is different and technology decisions often come down to business rules rather than a specific desire. You'll have to evaluate which is available and which best suits your needs and skills. Given your situation I'd say both could work, with Android's support I'd always say you'll have an easier time with REST :)

Answer (score 1):

both certainly have their fans, but the industry standard is overwhelmingly JSON at this point.

[SOAP or REST for Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services)