# Web service: RPC vs. RESTful = CISC vs. RISC?

Tags: web-services, rest, xml-rpc, json-rpc

I read some discussions about `RPC` style and `RESTful` web services.

So far I have the following 2 thoughts:

1. The argue between `RPC` and `REST` seems kind of *similar to* the argue
   between `CISC` and `RISC` instruction architecture. RPC looks
   forward to using a more complex vocabulary while REST just use a few
   common verbs.
2. The REST style just introduce the HTTP protocol as the middle-layer between client and server in the hope to `decouple` the 2 parties. Just like *[David Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_%28British_computer_scientist%29)* said:

   > All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of
   >   indirection, except of course for the problem of too many indirections.

So:

1. Are these 2 thoughts valid?
2. What are the most appropriate scenarios for these 2 styles, respectively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP or REST for Web Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services)

Comment: @Dai Actually, I have seen that thread. But real intention is to discuss my 2 thoughts. I changed my question.