# REST vs. SOAP for remote connection with PDA's

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf, soap

Some time ago, I designed an application to an exisitng system. The application allows updating some app in PDA's. It is a kind of a remote updater. It uses web service.

Before I designed the application I had read some articles about WCF - technology. Then, I found a piece of information about comparision between SOAP protocol and REST architecture. Then I understood that REST is more useful for devices such as mobile or PDA's. Because of REST requires less data than SOAP. Obviously, I read more about REST that it uses HTTP methods and I know a lot about it.

As a result, I decided to use the REST architecture and everything was good. The application is still using.

Recently, I have changed my job. There is an application which uses a web service to sending data to PDA's. The web service uses SOAP protocol. I was very surprised when I have seen it first time. In my job, nobody can't tell me about it with some reasons.

Summarizing my story, I need to know that I am right that REST is a better option for a web service when we need to connect with PDA's or both option are correct. I don't need some description between SOAP vs. REST. I would like to receive a precision answer.

Comment: _Apples and oranges_.  Essentially if your clients are JS or Ajax you are arguably better off with REST due to the JSON payload, the former have a hard time dealing with XML which is what SOAP utilises.  Will says it well here _"[If your consumers are more likely to be RIAs or Ajax clients, you will probably want something simpler than SOAP, and more native to the client (notably JSON).](http://stackoverflow.com/a/76755/585968)"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP or REST for Web Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services).  Pleas note that I disagree with the accepted answer on that page and agree with **insipied** and **John Saunders**.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/76755/585968) by Will I find more useful than the accepted _rant_