# Is REST preferred for CRUD operations

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I have just started exploring Web services(WS).
Sorry if this is a Naive question, I have been reading articles about REST WS and came across one article where it was mentioned to use REST for CRUD operations as Services while SOAP is used for accessing business logic as services.

For example,
getUser(User); // REST operation

addNumbers(int, int) // SOAP operation

Is it always true? Can we use them interchangeably?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link h[ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services?rq=1.). These are two different implementations to serve service oriented architecture. You can use both of them for both of the things.

Comment: Thanks, i will see it