# Questions related to Web-Services [RESTfull, RESTless, WSDL, Security]

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl

Thats the first time i gonna digg into webservices. Right now i am going through articles for RESTFull webservices, found from the stackoverflow discussions. Going through articles, i have few questions.

- What is the difference between RESTFull and RESTless
- What is WS-*? is it also a webservice standard? what is the difference between RESTFull and it?
- I got very basic knowledge of RESTfull services. I am wondering, how security is implemented in it?

I know most of you guys will say and recommend me to read these from different articles. which i will but for time being these questions are stuck in my head. I am not looking for some details or *referred* to other articles type answers. Just one liner or very basic difference.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guide to choosing between REST vs SOAP services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950/guide-to-choosing-between-rest-vs-soap-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no common understanding of the term "restless".

In my opinion a REST based system is RESTful.  Some people have decided that RESTful is a watered down version of REST.

WS-* is a set of standards implemented on top of the SOAP protocol and is alternative to building a REST based architecture.  Going into the differences is a large topic.  In summary, WS-* is based on using RPC for distribution of functionality, REST takes a different approach described in Roy Fielding's dissertation.

If you are doing REST over HTTP then you should use whatever security mechanisms HTTP provides.  e.g. Basic, Digest, SSL, OAuth, etc.

Comment: Actually, WS-* is a messaging platform that aims at solving heterogeneity issues and interoperability between platforms (OS, WS stacks etc). You can do RPC with Web services just as you can do it with JMS or other messaging standards but in most cases you run better with messaging-style interactions (cf Hohpe's EI Patterns). The reason why many people think WS-* is about RPC is mainly due to the fact that most WS-Stacks provide code generators for this purpose. However, RPC is not as loosely coupled as if you would use Web Services in the messaging style (doc/lit soap encoding etc).

Comment: Vanto The main reason people think that is because that was SOAP's original intent.  After SOAP 1.1 they realized the error of their ways and tried to push 1.2 as just a messaging system.  However, it was a bit late by then.